# NSHost taking an awfully long time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sockets, nshost

I have an iPhone app that is a client for an existing server application.

I am using the following code to connect, and this code was working fine. Today I started work on the project, and something odd is happening.

When I click "Connect" NSHost takes about 30-45 seconds to resolve and connect to the host. Once the connection is established, data transfer speeds are normal and fast.

I have the original client software (PC Application) connecting to the same server, and the connection is handled immediately!!

Perhaps someone can shed some light on the subject...

```
-(IBAction)tryConnection{
    [self showLogoffButtons];
    iPhone_PNPAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (iPhone_PNPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    settings=mainDelegate.settings; 
    [activityindicator startAnimating];
    sendState=0;

    NSHost* host;

    //30-45 second pause happens here (since I am using an IP Address)
    host = [NSHost hostWithAddress:settings.masterLocation];
    //NSHost returns (eventually) with the correct connection.

    if (!host)  {
        host = [NSHost hostWithName:settings.masterLocation];
    }
    if( host ) {
        [NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:[settings.masterPort intValue] inputStream:&iStream outputStream:&oStream] ;
        if( nil != iStream && nil != oStream ) {
            [iStream retain];
            [oStream retain];
            [iStream setDelegate:self];
            [oStream setDelegate:self];
            [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [iStream open];
            [oStream open]; 
        }else{
            [self resetConnectionAndScreen];
            self.navigationItem.prompt=@"Connection Error! Please check connection settings.";
        }

    }else{
        [self resetConnectionAndScreen];
        self.navigationItem.prompt=@"Connection Error! Please check connection settings.";
    }
}
```

//I am also now getting these warnings.**.. wth?! :)

- warning: no '+hostWithAddress:' method found
- warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
- warning: no '+hostWithName:' method found
- warning: 'NSStream' may not respond to '+getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:'

Comment: neither `NSHost` nor `getStreamstoHost...` exists on the iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my code to the following, which has resolved my issue.

```
-(IBAction)tryConnection{   
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)settings.masterLocation, [settings.masterPort intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);
    if (readStream && writeStream) {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

        iStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
        [iStream retain];
        [iStream setDelegate:self];
        [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [iStream open];

        oStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
        [oStream retain];
        [oStream setDelegate:self];
        [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [oStream open];     
    }
    if (readStream) CFRelease(readStream);
    if (writeStream) CFRelease(writeStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way of networking using cfsockets

http://randomsnippetsofusefulstuff.blogspot.com/